# Como usar uma function dentro de outra function no php?

Tags: php, funções

Estou precisando usar uma `function` dentro de outra `function` ...

```
function formata_data( $datacad ){
    $datacad = explode(' ', $data);
    $datacad = $data[0];
    $datacad = explode("-", $data);
    $datacad = $data[2]."-".$data[1]."-".$data[0];
    return $datacad;
}
```

Agora tenho uma função listar usuários que preciso retornar os dados inclusive a `data de cadastro` e formatá-la com a função criada.

```
function usuarios(){
    // listando usuarios
    $datacadastro = ("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $datacadastro = ; //usar a função formata_data para formatar o retorno da data no banco
}
```

Comment: Favor comentar a negativa para que eu reedite sem alterar o objetivo mas corrigindo a pergunta. Atenciosamente

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para usar a função criada por você, basta usar da mesma forma que qualquer uma pré-existente no PHP:

```
function usuarios(){
    // listando usuarios
    $datacadastro = formata_data("Y-m-d H:i:s");
}
```

Porém, sua função precisa retornar algo, senão não vai te ajudar muito. [Falta colocar no `return` o que é que a função deve retornar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/97257/revisions). Veja:

```
function formata_data( $datacad ){
    $datacad = explode(' ', $data);
    $datacad = $data[0];
    $datacad = explode("-", $data);
    $datacad = $data[2]."-".$data[1]."-".$data[0];
    return $datacad; // Aqui acrescentamos o que deve ser retornado.
}
```

Comment: Perfeita a aplicação da function formata_data() dentro de outra function conforme explicado ... ***<?php echo formata_data($linha['datacad']); ?>*** ... Obrigado